# Mercurial abort: index ... is corrupted

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I get the following error when trying to clone from the production repo.

```
abort: index data/HR3/globals.php.i is corrupted!
```

After which mercurial promptly farts out on me and fails to clone. I've tried removing the file in question from the production repo, and that failed. I also tried deleting the .hg directory in the production repo and re-adding and committing all of the files. This produces the same error.

Just fyi, I'm trying to clone the current production copy of our app to our test server. Our test server is running in Virtual Box.

***UPDATE***

I fixed the issue by deleting the globals file and then deleting the .hg directory and re-running "hg init" and "hg add ." and "hg commit."

Now I get an Internal server error when I try to clone. The following is the clone command I used.

```
sudo hg clone http://10.1.1.25/ www
```

Oddly enough, mercurial tells me that the "real" url is "10.1.1.25/HR3/index.php" which is most definitely not my mercurial repository. I do not know why it is doing this. I checked in my server logs, and the following error is what Apache crapped out.

```
[Thu Dec 16 12:25:30 2010] [error] [client 10.1.1.102] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/www/.hg/store/data/_h_r3/includes/_b_n_a_s/_b_n_a_s-_h_r_s201.php.i on line 22
```

Apparently the clone command is causing Mercurial to kick off PHP and make it try to parse something in Mercurial's data store?

***RESOLUTION***

I suspect this was caused by the fact that I have an index.php file at the root directory of my repository that does redirects. If you try and navigate directly to http:10.1.1.25 on our network, you're automatically directed to the index page, which is not the index.php page in the root directory. Somehow I think that this was causing php to kick off and try to parse items in the mercurial store. I've resolved this issue by cloning over ssh.

Comment: Your title has "Mercurial" yet you talk about a ".git" folder. Which one is it?

Comment: Whoops, I meant .hg. I recently switched from git to mercurial, so sometimes I get confused. I will edit.

Comment: Make sure the versions of Mercurial on server and client are similar. It could be you're trying to clone from an older client which doesn't understand something in the repository.

Comment: question1 - why do you use sudo?
question2 - your http address seems to be incorrect, it should be like this: `http://10.1.1.25/myProject` - without spaces. Try to enter your url in browser to see if it really works

Comment: The versions are the same. I'm using sudo so that mercurial can create the directory it's cloning to. It will gripe about permissions if I don't since my "working" directory is owned by root. As it turns out, there is an index.php file at the root directory of my project doing redirects. Could this be causing my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you publish your repo with the static-http method, from the same server as your development project lives. This method only works if the web server does not mess with $URL/.hg, which your one seems to do. check if you can download the .hg folder with `wget -r -np $URL/.hg` in a fresh folder and run `hg verify` there.

> Oddly enough, mercurial tells me that the "real" url is "10.1.1.25/HR3/index.php" which is most definitely not my mercurial repository.

I guess that your web server redirects some mercurial requests to your index.php url.

Answer (score 8):

I have faced such an error before. Try to run

```
hg verify
```

on your corrupted repository. Then follow the instructions from here:

http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-fix-mercurial-corrupt-repository-1926.html

Comment: Here's the goofy thing, I ran hg verify, and it says everything is kosher.

Comment: Where do you run it? That one should be run on the original repository

Comment: I ran it on the original repository. The one I'm trying to clone from. It's really weird.

Comment: That's really confusing... What version of mercurial you're using? Is it original mercurial or the one that was shipped with TurtoiseHG? Can you remove remove .hg directory one more time and commit all the files using another mercurial?

Comment: I'm using the original mercurial. I got it by running "apt-get install mercurial."

Comment: Mmmk, I didn't use a different mercurial, but I went ahead and removed the questionable file and deleted the .hg directory. I then re added and recommitted everything. I am now getting an internal server error when I try to clone. This is "[client 10.1.1.102] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/www/.hg/store/data/_h_r3/includes/_b_n_a_s/_b_n_a_s-_h_r_s201.php.i on line 22"

Comment: It is safe to say I have no idea what is going on. Why PHP is trying to parse something that's in my Mercurial data store is beyond me.

Comment: How do you clone it? How do your serve your repository?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to do that:

```
hg forget HR3/globals.php
hg commit
hg add HR3/globals.php
hg commit
```